# How to generate the unique identification of iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, jailbreak, udid

Our iosapp has been cracked. Because on some jailbreak machines, hackers have modified UDID, IMEI, IDFA, idfv, serial number and other system information that you can think of. And it looks random. We want to get the unique identification code of the machine, I want to get these iPhones with cracked apps installed to ban the devices. So I have two questions. 1.My current idea is to generate the unique identification of iPhone by calling the private API to get the hardware information. 2. If you have a better way to identify these devices, please let me know, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any private API, it may get rejected by Apple.

You can refer these options to get the unique device.
https://codeburst.io/unique-identifier-for-the-ios-devices-590bb778290d

Comment: Thank you, but I have detected many machines lower than IOS 11, so Apple's devicecheck doesn't work. As for uidevice, it's easy to be hook. I want to get hardware information as identification, but I haven't found relevant information

Comment: China's Internet Illegal industry chain is very developed, and we have no way to deal with it. As far as I know, IOS apps of many top companies in China call private APIs to identify devices and ban them

Comment: @MustangYM Since most of the users are on iOS 13, you can update your minimum support to iOS 11.  If that is not possible, as you mentioned, you can go with private APIs.